# R eval(as.name(paste0())) wrapper function for programmatic data.table changing

Tags: r, function, data.table, eval

I want to mimic STATA's local macros in R.
Basically, say I have a data.table that has a number of variables with the same starting string but different end strings; I'd like to programmatically change it. I know you can do this with eval(as.name(x)), but having that so many times in my code gets busy.
Anyone have a solution to this?

e.g.

```
library(data.table)    
a <- data.table(bob_1 = c(1:3), bob_2 = c(1:3), bob_3 = c(1:3))


# this works
for (i in c(1:3)){
  a[,(paste0("bob_",i)):=eval(as.name(paste0("bob_",i))) + 1]
}
a <- as.data.table(a)
print(a)

# this also works
a <- data.table(bob_1 = c(1:3), bob_2 = c(1:3), bob_3 = c(1:3))

for (i in c(1:3)){
  a[,(paste0("bob_",i)):=.SD + 1, .SDcols = (paste0("bob_",i))]
}

a <- as.data.table(a)
print(a)

# but this doesn't

sa <- function(...) {eval(as.name(paste0(...)))}

a <- data.table(bob_1 = c(1:3), bob_2 = c(1:3), bob_3 = c(1:3))

for (i in c(1:3)){
  a[,(paste0("bob_",i)):=sa("bob_",i) + 1]
}
# <<error message>>
a <- as.data.table(a)
print(a)
```

Comment: just as a note you might want to check out this pending PR which will introduce a more general way of programming data.table queries https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304

Comment: so these are new features that will be released in the next edition of data.table?

Comment: this is going to be great, by the way. so amazed at your work..

Comment: let's conservatively say "an upcoming edition" 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. I think a simple way to do it is like this:

```r
nms <- grep("^bob_", colnames(a), value = TRUE)
nms
# [1] "bob_1" "bob_2" "bob_3"

a[, (nms) := lapply(.SD, `+`, 1), .SDcols = nms ]
a
#    bob_1 bob_2 bob_3
#    <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     2     2     2
# 2:     3     3     3
# 3:     4     4     4
```

*How* one generates the `nms` vector I made here is arbitrary. In fact, it doesn't need to be the same on both sides:

```r
a <- data.table(bob_1 = c(1:3), bob_2 = c(1:3), bob_3 = c(1:3))
nms
# [1] "bob_1" "bob_2" "bob_3"
nmsout <- paste0(nms, "_out")
a[, (nmsout) := lapply(.SD, `+`, 1), .SDcols = nms ]
a
#    bob_1 bob_2 bob_3 bob_1_out bob_2_out bob_3_out
#    <int> <int> <int>     <num>     <num>     <num>
# 1:     1     1     1         2         2         2
# 2:     2     2     2         3         3         3
# 3:     3     3     3         4         4         4
```

Comment: this is great! didn't think of using lapply. Do you know why the sa <- function(...) {eval(as.name(paste0(...)))} fails? Is it something with the way that R is evaluating the string when it's called within a function?

Comment: Not off-hand, sorry. I don't work with meta-programming enough for that to be intuitive to me (and working outside of meta like this is fairly straight-forward, so I stick with it).

Comment: yeah, I think lapply tends to be a great solution if you're manipulating the entire data.table, but I feel like it gets confusing (at least for me) when manipulating slices of the data.table...

Comment: I don't disagree. The way I guard against that is this use of `.SDcols` and capturing it into a vector of names (`(nmsout)`). For instance, `DT[, c("aa","bb") := .(1, 2)]` does what one might expect (at least what *I* do :-), and I tend to stick with that nomenclature and structure. Once you grok that `.( ... )` is just `list(...)`, then `lapply` seems to make a lot more sense, as it always returns a `list`.